# I'm struggling to the translation from EBNF to BNF

Tags: compiler-construction, programming-languages, bnf, ebnf

I'm learning about compilers and concepts of programming languages.
How can I translate it?

Problem :

```
   <S> → (+ | -)[<C>]{<A>}
```

At first, I translated like this:

```
<S> -> epsilon
     | +<S>
     | -<S>
     | <C><S>
     | <A><S>
```

However, it has a problem that it can reproduce C!

Comment: Your question is unclear.   *What* can (re?)produce *C* and why is that bad?  It would be really helpful if you showed the stages by which you produced the answer you got, and the justification for each step.

Answer (score 2):

Your BNF version can not only produce multiple `<C>`s, but also multiple `+`s and `-`s (or zero, which would also be different from the original grammar).

To fix these issues, you'll need to introduce additional non-terminals. Specifically you could have one that matches just `{<A>}` and one that matches `[<C>]`. Your definition of `<S>` could then be:

```
<S> -> + <OptionalC> <RepeatedA>
     | - <OptionalC> <RepeatedA>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your EBNF original is not recursive in `<S>`, but your trial BNF is.  If you want the BNF to generate the same language, you shouldn't do that.  Also, your EBNF can't generate `epsilon`, so you shouldn't add that to your `<S>`-production, either.

As the other answer says, you need to introduce additional non-terminals:

```
<S> -> <plusminus> <optionalC> <repeatedA>
<plusminus> -> + | -
<optionalC> -> <C> | epsilon
<repeatedA> -> <A> <repeatedA> | epsilon
```

This is a straightforward translation of the EBNF elements in your original grammar.  Even if you have additional requirements (such as epsilon-elimination), you should start with this kind of step.

Note that the `<S>` rule is not recursive.  Also, although `epsilon` is used for some additional nonterminals, it is not part of the `<S>` or `<plusminus>` rules, so that, as in the EBNF original, `<S>` cannot produce it.